# Rename all files including a bracket (

Tags: bash, shell, quoting

I have a directory filled with a lot of files, some of which have brackets in them; e.g. `a(file).ext`,`an(other)file.ext`, etc. My goal is to rename them into something like this: `a_file_.ext` or `an?other?file.ext`. (doesn't matter what character).

the reason for this is because certain console applications can't deal with these brackets and think it's some kind of command.

things I already tried:

```
$ rename ( ? *(*
$ for f in *(*; do mv $f ${f//(/?}; done
$ for f in "*(*"; do mv $f ${f//\"(\"/\"?\"}; done
```

and the like.
It could be that I'm not understanding these rename functions. (I do know that these only work for "(" and that I have to do them again for ")")
So could someone also give some more explanation about it's syntax and why it won't work?

All in Bash.

Comment: You've got a bunch of bugs here stemming from missing/inadequate quotes

Comment: ...speaking of which, if you're not going to be careful about quotes, you absolutely shouldn't use `?`s in your filenames.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider:

```
(shopt -s nullglob; for f in *[\(\)]*; do mv "$f" "${f//[()]/_}"; done)
```

- `(` and `)` are syntax, and need to be escaped to be unambiguously referred to as literals.
- Setting the `nullglob` option makes the glob expand to nothing at all, rather than itself, if no files match. Putting the code in a subshell prevents this configuration change from persisting beyond the single command.
- Using quotes around expansions is mandatory if you don't want those expansions to be subject to string-splitting and globbing.

Comment: I'll add my usual recommendation for `mv -i` or `mv -n` to avoid accidentally overwriting files if there's a name conflict; otherwise, looks good!

Comment: Should't I use 'shopt -u nullglob' afterwards to unset it?

Comment: @KoneLinx, you don't need to because of the subshell. Parenthesis tell the shell to fork off a copy of itself and run the enclosed code in that copy; changes to variables, settings, and other process-local state thus go away when the subshell ends.